# Update User's lastLogin property after login

Tags: security, spring, grails, groovy, authentication

my user-domain has a field called 'lastLogin' which i want to update after login (self-exaplantoy).
after restarting tomcat (dev env) i get the following exception:

*groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static photoo.user.User.findById() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [2] Possible solutions: findAll(groovy.lang.Closure), find(groovy.lang.Closure)*

i use the following code in my Config.groovy:

```
// callback event, after a successful login
grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    def user = User.findById(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
    User.withTransaction {
        if(!user.isAttached())
            user.attach()
        user.lastLogin = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true)
    }
}
```

How can avoid the exception and why is it occuring??
thx

Answer (score 3):

finally i found the mistake. loading the user in the withTransaction-block is the solution.

```
// dont load before
// def user = User.findById(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
User.withTransaction {
        def user = User.findById(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
        if(!user.isAttached())
            user.attach()
        user.lastLogin = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might just need to use User.get(). This is what I have:

```
onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->

    // handle AuthenticationSuccessEvent
    def autservice = appCtx.authenticateService
    def user = autservice.userDomain()
    println "user: ${user.id}:${user}}"
    def request = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SecurityRequestHolder.getRequest()
    def session = request.getSession(false)
    if (user) {

        def person = Person.get(user.id)

        def lang = person.preferredLanguage
        if (session) {
            session.lang = lang
        }
    }
}
```